# how to extract the last word of line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to extract the last word of each line in notepad++. For this purpose i used the regular expression `(\w+)$` in find what text box, it showed all the last word highlighted after the search. but i don't know how i will extract these words.  Below is a look of my file

```
gene expression
gene
B activation
B
surface receptor
cell activation
proliferation
T lymphocyte
oxygen intermediate
activation
B
complex
expression
signaling cascade
tyrosine kinase activity
tyrosine kinase
A2
metabolite
formation
B activation
B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- Search: `(.* )(\w+)$`
- Replace with: `$2`

to delete all others except the last word in each line.

Comment: thx alot. It worked. nd if i have to extract the last two words then what changes will i have to made in the above regex???

Comment: @ShaheenGul Just replace searching part by `(.* )(.* \w+)$`.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the last word of each line, you can use the command line `cc.gc ^-1w` of the plugin ConyEdit.